# Google Checkout and App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-checkout

I've followed the [Order Processing tutorial](http://code.google.com/apis/checkout/developer/Google_Checkout_Custom_Processing_How_To.html) to receive and handle order notifications in my GAE application from Google Checkout.

Everything works OK in the sandbox environment. I can send a fake order and the app gets a notification and handles the order.

When I switch to the production environment and make a real order, I can see the order in the Google Checkout Merchant account but I don't receive any notifications.

To switch to production I simply edit my `ApiContext` object to use `Environment.Production` and the real merchant id and key. The Integration settings are the same. I've also tried changing the callback URL to use HTTPS (https://blah.appspot.com/not) but still nothing.

What am I missing?

Comment: Are you failing to receive the notification serial number or failing to receive a response from your notification history request?

Comment: Thanks for asking. I don't receive any requests to the callback URL. I can't see any hits to the endpoint in the logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "Integration Console" in the Checkout Merchant Center gives you information about the callbacks (XML sent, XML received, HTTP errors, etc.). Hopefully you can figure out the problem from that data. Some related links below:

https://checkout.google.com/support/sell/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=72217

http://code.google.com/apis/checkout/developer/Google_Checkout_XML_API.html#integration_issues_console

http://code.google.com/apis/checkout/articles/Troubleshoot_Integration_Console_Errors.html

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I don't know what happened but this was fixed on its own! Thanks for the links.